# "No main manifest attribute" when creating Kotlin jar using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jvm, manifest, manifest.mf

When creating a jar from my Kotlin code and running it, it says "No main manifest attribute".
When looking at the manifest.mf, it has this content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

When looking at the file in the source, it has this content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MyMainClass
```

When manually copying the source manifest to the jar, it runs perfectly.

[Screenshot of my artifact settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDHfF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the dependent jars has a `MANIFEST.MF` file, it will override your custom one which defines the `Main-Class`.

In order to address this problem you should do the following:

- Disable the [alphabetical ordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjbEH.png)
- [Change items ordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3urG.png) so that item which has `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file is the first in the list
- Your custom `MANIFEST.MF` will be picked up by IntelliJ IDEA and [displayed for the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITdhO.png) artifact.

See the [related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116209) for more details.

You can also use Gradle or Maven to generate the fat jar instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I marked your answer as accepted answer I took the gradle route using this page: https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/

Answer (score 15):

I got this error with Gradle and Kotlin.
I had to add in my `build.gradle.kts` an explicit manifest attribute:

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MainKt"
    }
}
```

From the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example), it's better to create a fatJar task to englobe all of the runtime dependencies in case you encounter `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors

Answer (score 4):

So far the simplest and best solution I've found is using [Ktor Gradle Plugin](https://ktor.io/docs/fatjar.html)

```
plugins {
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.2.3" // Check if it's latest
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.ApplicationKt")
}

ktor {
    fatJar {
        archiveFileName.set("fat.jar")
    }
}
```

Run it with ./gradlew buildFatJar

Answer (score 1):

1.Add the following task definition in the build script

```
tasks.jar {
manifest {
    attributes["Main-Class"] = "MainKt"
}
configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
    from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
}
}
```

2. Then the jar tasks (Tasks | build | jar) again from the right hand sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

**For Spring boot apps:**

What worked for me (gradle kotlin) in build.gradle.kts

1. add spring boots plugin &. apply dependency management

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.7"
}
apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
```

2. set your main class

```
springBoot {
    mainClass.set("com.example.Application")
}
```

Found this all by reading up on spring-boot docs found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/)