# How to export Kotlin module to .jar

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I want to export my kotlin program to a runnable file (be it .jar, .exe, whatever) so that other people will be able to use my programs, however I can't figure out how to do this. I'm using IntelliJ Community edition

My only code is a file called Main.kt containing:

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

I understand I need to set up an artifact, but I'm not sure what to put in the artifact settings, and when I build it [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsWfI.png), the .jar file [doesn't output anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttZzj.png).

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** After running `java -jar "Simple Kotlin Test_jar.jar"` it comes back with `no main manifest attribute, in Simple Kotlin Test_jar.jar`

Comment: Did you try to run it using `java -jar "filename.jar"` command? By default `.jar` file may be associated with `javaw` on Windows which doesn't have a console for the output and is normally used for the GUI apps. In order to get the console output you need to run it with `java` instead of `javaw` command.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: See https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/kotlin-basics-create-executable-kotlin-jars-using-gradle-d17e9a8384b9. You need to specify the main class as `MainKt` in this case for the jar mainfest.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894502/104891. Make sure the manifest specifying the `Main-class: MainKt` is at the top.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! If you add your comment as an answer ill tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `Main-class` for the jar manifest. In this case it would be `MainKt`.

Make sure this manifest is [at the top of the artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894502/104891) so that other jars don't override it.

The app should be also started using `java -jar jarname.jar` to get the console output, otherwise it will use `javaw` and you will not see the output.