# IntelliJ IDEA: How to specify main class in Kotlin?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I try to build a jar with Intellij Idea with Kotlin Gradle project.
Idea doesn't see my main class when I try to configure Artifact

here's my Gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.60'
    id 'application'
}
group 'org.vladdrummer'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MovieQuizBackendKt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-kotlin:1.0.0-alpha"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Here's structure :

[image: structure]

Here's main class :

```
class MovieQuizBackend {

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Server()
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `MovieQuizBackend` look like? Does it run in IntelliJ IDEA while not in jar?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I added it. No, it doesn't add as a main class to run either

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Kotlin language entry point is not a method inside the class (a class with the `Kt` suffix in the name is generated automatically from a file). See [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started.html).

Your code inside the `MovieQuizBackend.kt` file needs to be changed to the following:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    Server()
}
```

Just remove the `class MovieQuizBackend {` and `}` at the end.

You can even omit `args` if you don't plan to pass any:

```
fun main() {
    Server()
}
```

Another option is to use `@JvmStatic` annotation inside the `companion object`:

```
class MovieQuizBackend {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args : Array<String>) {
            Server()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this way the main class is named just `MovieQuizBackend` instead of `MovieQuizBackendKt`, so you will need to change it in `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MovieQuizBackend'
    }
}
```

Comment: It's so weird. I was wondering why we need kt files without classes in it and should I add @JvmStatic. But all this looks odd

Comment: It may look odd for the long time Java developers, but for the new programmers it's quite natural and allows to save a lot of typing. Try to explain a new student starting to write a code why in Java you need a class and the static main method just to print "hello world". Kotlin tries to simplify things and decrease the amount of code you need to write.

Comment: You don't even need `args: Array<String>` if you don't use them.

Comment: Do you build the jar using Gradle or IntelliJ IDEA artifact?

Comment: @CrazyCoder artifact via Idea

Comment: Try Gradle instead, building artifact from IDEA may be complicated because of the included jars order which may override the manifest file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54894502/104891. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45169655/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder is it Gradle->Tasks->Build->build ? it says A problem was found with the configuration of task ':startScripts'.
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.

Comment: To build a proper jar with dependencies using Gradle you will need to adjust the script, see https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/kotlin-basics-create-executable-kotlin-jars-using-gradle-d17e9a8384b9. Or check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469365/building-a-self-executable-jar-with-gradle-and-kotlin with the shadow jar example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to previous answer I realized my class was

```kotlin
class MyClass {
  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  }
}
```

I had to change it to

```kotlin
class MyClass 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
}
```

After that it worked as expected.

I also added in my `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
 ...
 application
}
...
application {
    mainClass.set("co.example.MainClass")
}
...
```