# "no main manifest attribute" kotlin executable jar

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm getting the `no main manifest attribute` error when running the executable jar created from my kotlin project. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Community Edition) on macOS 13.6.3. I created a JAR artifact with the "From modules with dependencies" option and built the artifact from the Build->Build Artifacts... menu option. The project contains just the default sample code included for new Kotlin project and has no dependencies (it's uploaded [here](https://github.com/mdobric/KotlinExecJarSample/tree/main/ExecJar)). The manifest properties for the artifact correctly specify the main class and src/main/resources/MANIFEST.MF contains `Main-Class: MainKt`. However, when I build the artifact, the manifest contained within it does not contain that attribute and I get the previously mentioned error. I tried the answers suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892529/no-main-manifest-attribute-when-creating-kotlin-jar-using-intellij-idea) but none worked. What is the correct way to create an executable jar from a kotlin project?

Comment: How are you building the JAR?

Comment: From the Build -> Build Artifacts... menu option. That shows available artifacts with the options to build, rebuild, clean, and edit. I tried both the build and rebuild options.

Comment: I think doing that in IntelliJ doesn't invoke Gradle. You could try building the JAR via Gradle or configure the main somewhere in IntelliJ.

Comment: Please, file an issue https://kotl.in/issue.